# Android: Why gets the Mapactivity recycled?

Tags: android, mapactivity, recycle

I´m starting a MapActivity from another Activity **ONCE!**
When i want to leave the MapActiivty (Google Maps), he reloaded the map...
The LogCat says:

MapActivity(13290): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@41e24c30

MapActivity(13290): Recycling map object.

When I quit it after the reload, he leaves the app correctly...

What can I do?

Comment: MapActivity? You should be using MapFragment in the newer Android Maps SDK. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: nevertheless this problem has to be solved too... Someone know this error??